# Solve non-negative least squares p‌r‌o‌b‌l‌e‌m "xA=b"

Tags: python, r, matlab, math, least-squares

I want to find the non-negative least squares solution for "xA=b". I'm happy for answers to be in Python, Matlab or R.

`A` is a 6*10 matrix, and `b` is 8192*10 matrix.

I found some functions: `least_squares` and `nnls` in Python, and `lsqnonneg` in Matlab.

`nnls` and `lsqnonneg` are only used for `Ax=b`.

My implementation of `least_squares` give me an error:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

from scipy.optimize import least_squares

spec=pd.read_csv('spec.csv',sep=',',header=None)
y=pd.read_csv('y.csv',sep=',',header=None)

spec=np.array(spec).T
y=np.array(y)

spec=spec[(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,9),:]
y=y[(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,9),:]

print(spec.shape,y.shape)

def fun(a, x, y):
    return a*x-y

a0=np.ones((8192,6))
a=least_squares(fun, a0, args=(y.T[:,0], spec.T[:,0]),
                           bounds=([np.zeros((8192,6)),
                           np.ones((8192,6))*np.inf]))
```

> runfile('C:/Users/Documents/lsq.py', wdir='C:/Users/Documents')
>   (8, 8192) (8, 6)
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       runfile('C:/Users/wangm/Documents/lsq.py', wdir='C:/Users/Documents')
>
> File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 714, in runfile
>       execfile(filename, namespace)
>
> File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 89, in execfile
>       exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
>
> File "C:/Users/Documents/lsq.py", line 30, in 
>       np.ones((8192,6))*np.inf]))
>
> File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize_lsq\least_squares.py", line 742, in least_squares
>      raise ValueError("x0 must have at most 1 dimension.")
>
> **ValueError: `x0` must have at most 1 dimension.**

Comment: As seen in the duplicate: `x*A=b` is the same as `A^T*x^T=b^T`

Comment: @AnderBiguri, it's useful to note that it can be done really easily in Matlab without any equation transformations though? Matlab likely just takes care of that step for you internally...

Comment: @Wolfie Yes it is useful, your answer is good, you should leave it there. It has been long since I used `mldivide` myself but according to the docs it does solve `x*A=b`. I assume it always solves that, but we never look at the shape of the output (we get 1x20 instead of 20x1 and we just do not care!)

Comment: @Wolfie    here can not pre-multiply by A, because A is 6*10 matrix, and b is 8192*10 matrix.So I pre-multiply by b.T,.

> A=y.T
> b=spec.T
> new_A=b.T
> new_b=new_A*b*np.linalg.pinv(A)

Comment: @user24067, yes I deleted that comment. For equation transformations see Ander's comment and the duplicate question. For a quick solution see my answer.

Comment: @AnderBiguri        I know that , but I need non-negative.

Comment: @user24067 yes? Why does transposing your matrix make it impossible to use a non negative solving algorithm? Take about 3 seconds to think why my suggestion solves your question

Comment: Just google: `lsqnonneg`

Answer (score 1):

This is such a common matrix problem that you can do it in one character in Matlab using [`mrdivide`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mrdivide.html).

From the docs:

> `mrdivide`, `/`: Solve systems of linear equations `xA = B` for `x`

```matlab
% Option 1, shorthand:
x = B/A;
% Option 2, longhand:
x = mrdivide(B,A);
```

Comment: but the solution is not non-negative

Comment: Then your inputs don't yield a non-negative solution? You can't force the solution to be positive if that doesn't satisfy your equation! Give a smaller example of inputs and you expected outputs, and why this isn't achieved using the above.

Comment: The function is overdetermined, "then X = A\B is the solution in the least squares sense to the under- or overdetermined system of equations AX = B. " Now I need "non-negative least squares" instead of  "least squares".Is it impossible?